# Python, best practices importing config file

Tags: python, import, flask

I am creating a Flask web application and I have a file storing some configurations. However, some of the inner modules would need to refer to the config.py which lies two directories above. I am using relative imports which I think is a bad practice and is not flexible.

Structure:

```
workspace:
    app:
      database:
         __init__.py
         database.py
    config.py
```

In my database.py file, I am importing config as `import ...config`.
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out how config is managed in [Flasky](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky). Basically, `config.py` resides in the application root, just like in your project.

Then in your app folder you initiate the application as a package, i.e., by adding the `__init__.py` file.

`__init__.py` contains an import statement to your `config`:

`from config import config`

Then you can use [Flask blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/) to initiate calls to your config. Also take a look at how [larger applications](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/) are managed in Flask.

All in all, it will require about four changes to your existing source:

1. Make your application a package by creating the `__init__.py` file.
2. Add the import statement to `__init__.py` in your root `app` directory.
3. In your module directory (in this case `database/`) create an `__init__.py` file to allow that module to be used as a blueprint in your larger flask application. [Note in this case module refers to a modularized part of your application; **not** to a python module; confusing I know.]
4. Back in `app/__init__.py` import the blueprint, i.e.,

```
from .database import database as db_blueprint
app.register_blueprint(db_blueprint)
```

It's a bit of leg work but it's really great if your interested in writing more complex applications and (of course) organizing your projects.

Answer (score 0):

Generally I'd recommend module level imports in cases like these, so something along the lines of `from application import config`
Since your `config.py` is in a bare directory that's not really possible of course... unless you move the `config.py` to some place within your app.

An alternative solution might be to create a class/app that manages your configuration so you always have it available.

Having that said, I'm sure I understand the need for this config file. Flask handles configuration for you automatically right? Simply import your app and use `app.config` to get your configuration.